Self-Promotion 2016
It’s time for community promotion ads again. 
For those who don’t know what that means: graduated StackExchange sites  each have a meta question where users can submit ads. (Some examples: Security.SE, Math.SE, Academia.SE, Physics.SE). When upvoted at least six (6) times, the promo-image will be displayed on the main site. Keeping it short: 
this provides a good way for us to promote Crypto.SE on other StackExchange websites. 
Now, to avoid that we might miss out on anything, I quickly whipped up a first image while bluntly sticking to our new Crypto.SE design/identity. 
Of course – and I bet we will all agree to that – this is not the most creative promotion image for Crypto.SE we’ve ever seen and chances are that you can do better… much better. Therefore, I would herewith like to ask/invite/request you to post your own creative “self-promotion image” suggestion(s) so the community can vote on things (like we once did way back in August 2013).
Tech Details:

The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels (or double that if retina).
Must be hosted through the standard SE image uploader (imgur)
Must be GIF or PNG
No animated GIFs
Absolute limit on file size of 40 KB 150 KB (StackExchange updated this Jan 18, 2016).
If background of image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border surrounding it.

The embed code looks like this:
[![cryptography.stackexchange.com][1]][2]

   [1]: https://image-url
   [2]: https://crypto.stackexchange.com 
Resources:
To provide a helping hand, I‘ve rebuild my initial community ad from scratch using Inkscape, saving it as an editable SVG. It is available – together with a growing collection of stuff that might help – at a dedicated github repository called (drumroll) “Crypto.SE-Resources”. Rip it apart for your designs as you wish… just remember to adher to StackExchange copyright.
Deadline:
To give all potential voters the chance to discover this question, to submit their suggestion, and/or to vote on suggestions posted here… I’ld say that we put up a deadline at Feb. 18, 2016 (4 weeks from now) to see what we‘ve got and pick a winner according to the individual upvotes gained here. If the deadline turns out to be too narrow for some reason, we can always give it another push into the future when time comes.
Last but not least: 
To make voting easy, please post each suggestion as a separate answer.

Final Results

Design by “squeamish ossifrage” with a total of +12 (12 upvotes, 0 downvotes). – link
Design by “PyRulez” with a total of +9 (9 upvotes, 0 downvotes). – link
Design by “e-sushi” with a total of +8 (8 upvotes, 0 downvotes). – link
Design by “e-sushi” with a total of +6 (8 upvotes, 2 downvotes). – link
Design by “e-sushi” with a total of 0 (3 upvotes, 2 downvotes + 1 downvote via comment). – link

I updated the community ads at Security.SE, Math.SE, Academia.SE and Physics.SE. If anyone knows any other SE sites where it may make sense to promote Crypto.Se, please feel invited to post them accordingly.
The embed code of the design that won by votes:
[![cryptography.stackexchange.com][1]][2]

[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/AkQzj.png
[2]: https://crypto.stackexchange.com


Suggested text: "When Alice needs your message, we're here to help."

@PyRulez Nice one! Created and posted it accordingly. Also dropped a heads-up at our chat.

@e-sushi thanks for doing this for us!

@mikeazo My pleasure… after all, my efforts would have been futile without the contributions, comments, and votes by community members.

I tried e-sushi's design with a different background:

(If anyone wants to play with it, here's the background image by itself)

(Edited to add vignette to background. Check the edit history for the previous version.)

Looking at the votes, it seems we have a clear winner. Congratulations! (accepted answer accordingly)

As suggested by PyRulez…

SVG resource etc. available at github.


SVG resource etc. available at github.


SVG resource etc. available at github.


SVG resource etc. available at github.

Would down-vote, but I don't have rep here. So, consider this my down-vote due to a philosophical disagreement with the first line in the image.

@Iszi No worries. I’ll count your downvote when the deadline is reached and things are summed up.
